# Serilog, .NET framework, IIS, and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis

I am experiencing an issue with Serilog, IIS, SQL Server and .NET Framework. I have used Serilog with .NET 5 micro services and it works perfectly. The SQL Server permissions appear to be fine. I can locally run the .NET Framework solution and target SQL Server directly with the connection string.

I have added:

```
<section name="MSSqlServerSettingsSection" 
         type="Serilog.Configuration.MSSqlServerConfigurationSection, Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"/>
```

to the `web.config`. And further down in `web.config`, I have:

```
<MSSqlServerSettingsSection>

    <!-- SinkOptions parameters -->
    <BatchPostingLimit Value="150"/>
    <BatchPeriod Value="00:00:15"/>

    <!-- ColumnOptions parameters -->
    <AddStandardColumns>
        <add Name="LogEvent"/>
    </AddStandardColumns>
    <RemoveStandardColumns>
        <remove Name="MessageTemplate"/>
    </RemoveStandardColumns>
    <TimeStamp ConvertToUtc="true"/>
</MSSqlServerSettingsSection>
```

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: I cannot understant what you mean. What error did you get or anything block the application? If it works now but you want to get another solution, you need to describe what kind of solution you want.

Comment: the problem is .net framework app on IIS is not communicating to the sql server even though the dotnet5 microservice app hosted on IIS is using the exact same connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just posting a resolution to this question.  there was a nuget package: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0

and went through a recent nuget update to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.4.0.0.

the csproj was still referencing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0

```xml
<!-- <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets'))" />-->

    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.4.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.4.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets'))" />
```